# iterate over two large dataframes to pull values way to vectorize?

Tags: pandas, loops, optimization, iterator, vectorization

i have a dataframe which is 1mm rows which looks like this

```
shipname       timestamp
0                  11/1/2019
0                  11/2/2019
...                  ...
100                10/1/2018
```

i have a 2nd dataframe which has a series of data as follows

```
shipname       dateorigin     datedestination
0                10/1/2019       10/5/2019
0                10/20/2019      11/10/2019
...
99               11/1/2019       11/20/2019
```

I want to run a function which returns the index in DF2 if shipname is in DataFrame 2 and if timestamp is between dateorigin and datedestination.

currently I am doing this using df.iterrows, but it is slowing down my PC and making python almost unuseable. also there are some instances where there might be >1 value in DF2 where this is true (in which case I would just like to return the first value). so far I have been using the code

```
for t in shipbase.itertuples():
    try:
        idx = (t.shipname== df.shipname) & (t.Timestamp >= df.DateOrigin) & (
                t.Timestamp <= df.DateDestination)
        list_index.append(df.loc[idx].index.values)
    except ValueError:
        list_index.append(np.nan)
        print(t)

any help to get this code to work better / optimize would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to vectorize, but cant think of an easy solution.
```

Comment: see merge + series.between

Answer (score 1):

If you don't run out of memory you can try the following:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='shipname')
# If you can do the merge, and run out of memory after, try to delete df1 and df2 by
# del df1, df2

df= df[df['timestamp'].between(df['dateorigin'], df['datedestination'])]
```

Remark that the `pd.merge` can duplicate some of your rows since `shipname` value looks like to not be unique in either dataframe